# Improve kernel boot time

Tags: kernel, boot, time

I am using **OMAPL138** and **kernel version 2.6.37** and I would like to improve the boot time. By analyzing the kernel boot process I think it is taking a long time at **MII PHY CONFIGURATION**. The printscreen is shown below and we can see that it takes almost 19 seconds to configure **MII PHY**. Is it possible to improve this and make the boot run faster?

[image: kernel boot process]